# Consuming Webservice through it's reference again

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

Current situation:

I made two projects , one is console project to consume a soap Web service to read the data and rewrite it into the database and a second project as asp.net project to read same data and show it on page as tables . I create inside the console project all the services and models which i need to extract data from target platform and it's work fine.. I need but to reflect this data to table on page .. it's actually easy if i want to write spaghetti code .. I do not want to do the same things into asp.net , want to reuse my previous implementation inside asp.net project. Shortly i need my asp.net just as presentation layer and data and it's logic belong to the console project ..

What i did:

I create view and passed lists of objects i.e (Customers) using the reference of interface after i injected it through the constructor , this interface has all the implementation methods(read,update..etc) of that web service .Before i forget i managed the instantiation as Transient between concrete class i.e (CustomerService) which implement that interface i.e (IEntityService) ..

What i got :

```
exception : "Configuration files are not supported."
source :   "System.Private.ServiceModel"
```

This exception will be thrown in each time my method tries to call instance of webservices from the reference in the console project ..

Hopefully that's understood so far..

Comment: Do I understood you correctly that you have 2 projects: one console app with logic and another one with asp code? And you referencing console project in asp project? If that is right you need to create separate project (class library), place or you business logic there (the logic you are willing to reuse). Then reference this library in console and asp project.

Comment: yes you got it , that sound good .. if i got you right! with my Case will be this class library include only that references of that web service and it's implementation methods, right??

Comment: Yeah, but not reference - exact code. Write these methods in this class library and call them in console and web apps. So shared code will be written only once - in class library.

Comment: that is amazing .. that's what i want , i will tell about the updates .. thanks

Comment: Feel free to show your repo if it is publicly available :)